# How to flip all platforms in a gameboard?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I'm working on a simple platformer game in XNA where when the player exits the screen, the screen flips. I divided my screen into a Board which consists of `Platforms[x,y]`. I have a function to show/hide platforms which look like this.

```
 public void Show(int a, int b)
    { 
        Platforms[a,b].Visible=true;
    }

    public void Hide(int a, int b)
    {
        if (Platforms[a, b].Visible == true)
            Platforms[a, b].Visible = false;
    }
```

I can flip the board manually by hiding the previous platforms and showing the new one but it involves manual calculation and very tedious. The flipped platform should be something like: 
 `[Math.abs(x - maxX),y]`, I think it will work but I'm having a hard time making the method.

I came up with this method:

```
  public void flip(int a, int b)
    {
        if (Platforms[a, b].Visible == true)
        {
            this.Hide(a, b);
            this.Show(Math.Abs(a - 15), b);


        }
    }
```

But there's a problem if the original board and the flipped board has intersecting platforms (meaning the same x and y), the platform is hidden in the flipped board.

Comment: Not an answer by any stretch, but in your `Hide` method, you don't need to do the check if it's true.

Comment: "Having hard time" not describing any problems.